# Pushing multi-arch docker image to Nexus in separate build step

Tags: docker, gitlab, cross-platform

Here's the problem:

We need to do multi-arch docker image builds (this part is solved) in Gitlab CI and push the whole multi-arch image to Nexus (this is a problem).

Reason is that in our build pipeline we NEED (!) to separate build from push - with normal docker build we used "docker save" and "docker load" but this will not work with docker buildx when creating multi-platform builds.

Creating separate images for different platforms is out of the question as well because of the logistics involved (we need to address three different types of CPU, namely Linux on x86, MacOS on ARM and Raspberry Pi).

Is there not a way to do something like:

a) in "build" step:

docker save ...

b) in "push" step:

docker load ...
docker push ...

but for multiarch builds done with docker buildx?

Clarification:

We need to do save / load because Gitlab CI has 3 servers available on our setup and it will often switch between those servers for different stages.